# Login to web form through C#

Tags: c#, webforms

I know that there are TONS of questions asking the very same thing that I am asking on this very site, but I cannot get my login to work correctly.

The site that I am attempting to log into is located [here](http://isitclean.net/index.php)

The code that I am using to do so is:

```
        private void wb_scanFile_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (wb_scanFile.Url.ToString() == "http://isitclean.net/index.php")
        {
            string formUrl = "http://isitclean.net/index.php"; // NOTE: This is the URL the form POSTs to, not the URL of the form (you can find this in the "action" attribute of the HTML's form tag
            string formParams = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "mine", "mypass");
            string cookieHeader;
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Method = "POST";
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
            req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
            {
                os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
        }
    }
```

What is the problem here? I don't understand why it's not filling in the text box correctly.

Comment: What HTTP result code do you get?

Comment: I want to fill out both of the text boxes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include another POST parameter `doLogin=1`.

The reason is that there is a hidden input in the login form called `doLogin`.

In all, there are 3 inputs in the HTML form `login_form`.

It's these types of things that need to be watched for when reverse engineering an HTML page.